# "isn't much" vs "aren't much" vs "aren't much of"

Tags: grammar

I am quite confused between

> 1. There aren't much of a differences between those two
> 2. There aren't many differences between those two
> 3. There isn't much of a difference between those two
> 4. There isn't much difference between those two

Can anyone point out the right ones and explain why please?
Thank you

Comment: 1.) is certainly wrong, the others are grammatical but need more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gramatically correct sentences are 2, 3 and 4.

- *"much of a"* refers to a singular subject
- *"much"* refers to a quality
- *"many"* refers to a plural subject

In number 1, the subject is "differences" which is plural.